# Using two vocabularies' terms at the same level in url filtering

Tags: drupal

I have two vocabularies ( **Man and Woman** ) with their regarding terms.

These terms are used as fields in content types **Men and Women** too. Now i wanna filter contents by content type and those vocabularies' terms by Views module ( custom view with name  **gallery** ) in help of Contextual Filters as below :

```
http://mysite.com/gallery/content-type/(Man or Woman)'s terms
```

something like this :

```
1 - http://mysite.com/gallery/men/jean
2 - http://mysite.com/gallery/women/jean
```

1st url "jean" term is for vocabulary Man and the 2th url "jean" term is for vocabulary Woman.

I should add 3 Filters, one for content type one for terms of Woman and one for terms of Man. but the two Man and Woman Vocabularies should be filtered at one **%**.

I know by using this kind of path **gallery/%/%** the work should be done **BUT** filtering from two vocabularies' terms in the second **%** in url is my problem.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Views won't be able to distinguish between "jean" in url #1 and #2 if you use a taxonomy filter validating with "tid from term name".

The quick and dirty way to solve this is with two views: gallery/men/% and gallery/women/%.

They will be identical except in their term filter, which you would set to validate by the appropriate vocabulary. (They would also differ in their regular filter for content type.)

The programmatic way to solve this would involve using the first contextual filter as input to the second so you can limit by vocabulary. For example, something like

```
$vocabulary = $view->args[0];  // assuming this is the machine name
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($view->args[1], $vocabulary);

return (!empty($term)) ? $term->tid : 0;
```